# SQL delete doesn't seem to be working

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Help please :-)
Following code is supposed to delete a record. It seems to execute OK, no error message and the NSLog shows "Record Deleted" message.  However the record is not deleted.  I have used Terminal to check and indeed the deleted record is still there.  The puzzling part is that I have very similar code to add and count records and they all seem to work... I am not an SQL expert, so I am hoping that an expert in this crowd can see the error.

Thanks

```
 (void) deleteRecord
 {
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &wfDataBase) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"About to Delete Record %d",currentID);
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DELETE from wfDataBase WHERE ID = %d", currentID];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(wfDataBase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
            l_status.text = @"Record Deleted";            
        else 
            l_status.text = @"Can't Delete";

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(wfDataBase);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have [evaluated](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) (`sqlite3_step(statement )`) the [compiled](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) statement (`sqlite3_prepare_v2(wfDataBase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)`)  before [destroying](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) it (`sqlite3_finalize(statement)`)?

Note: I'm not an expert on SQLite (indeed I don't know anything about SQLite) but I guess this is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Oops... That was indeed the problem.. the step statement was never executed... Thanks